# Get System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version.ToString(); from XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, reflection

Is there a chance to get:

```
System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version.ToString();
```

from XAML code?

```
<Window x:Class="TestWpf.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title=" **Here** " Height="700" Width="660"
        Name="myWindow" xmlns:my="clr-namespace:TestWpf">

</Window>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Define the property in code-behind with this value and use it in `XAML`.

Comment: Or just set the `Title` property in the MainWindow constructor. Saves you a property.

Comment: I would like to get it from XAML, without using code behind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use MarkupExtension for this:

```
public class Version : MarkupExtension
{
    public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
    {
        return System.Reflection.Assembly
                     .GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version.ToString();
    }
}
```

And to use it this way:

```
<Window x:Class="TestWpf.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="{my:Version}" 
    Height="700" Width="660"
    Name="myWindow" 
    xmlns:my="clr-namespace:TestWpf">

</Window>
```

Comment: Really?? Having a property in ViewModel seems more promising than having a `markupExtension`. This is not for which markupExtensions are used.

Comment: Well, once they are there, you can abuse them in whatever way you like... In any case,  this allows to get required info using XAML only, after,  of course, you have written the extension.

Answer (score 0):

In the code-behind of your `Window` create a property returning that string:

```
public string Version
{
    get
    {
        return System.Reflection.Assembly
            .GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Version.ToString();
    }
}
```

Then reference that from your XAML code:

```
<Window x:Class="TestWpf.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="{Binding Version, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" 
        Height="700" Width="660"
        Name="myWindow" 
        xmlns:my="clr-namespace:TestWpf">

</Window>
```

As far as I know there is no way to retrieve the version if the program currently running directly in XAML code. You will always have to use some kind of background code. That can be the codebehind as well as a view model, a MarkupExtension or some other kind of DataContext.

Comment: that's what I have now, but is there a chance to get it without using code behind?

Comment: Well, If you have a view model, or some other DataContext, you could create such a property there.

Comment: Well, if there is no way to do in desirable way.  I will accept your answer as correct.